# How to merge pandas on string contains?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 dataframes that I would like to merge on a common column. However the column I would like to merge on are not of the same string, but rather a string from one is contained in the other as so:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'column_a':['John','Michael','Dan','George', 'Adam'], 'column_common':['code','other','ome','no match','word']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column_b':['Smith','Cohen','Moore','K', 'Faber'], 'column_common':['some string','other string','some code','this code','word']})
```

The outcome I would like from `d1.merge(d2, ...)` is the following:

```
column_a  |  column_b
----------------------
John      |  Moore    <- merged on 'code' contained in 'some code' 
Michael   |  Cohen    <- merged on 'other' contained in 'other string'  
Dan       |  Smith    <- merged on 'ome' contained in 'some string'  
George    |  n/a
Adam      |  Faber    <- merged on 'word' contained in 'word'
```

Comment: Why is `'John'` not also matched with `K` because of `'this code'`

Comment: @ALollz that's because 'some code' comes first

Comment: Unfortunately Pandas does not currently have a built-in function for merging on a custom function like string contains

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### New Answer

Here is one approach based on pandas/numpy.

```
rhs = (df1.column_common
          .apply(lambda x: df2[df2.column_common.str.find(x).ge(0)]['column_b'])
          .bfill(axis=1)
          .iloc[:, 0])

(pd.concat([df1.column_a, rhs], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
 .rename(columns={0: 'column_a', 1: 'column_b'}))

  column_a column_b
0     John    Moore
1  Michael    Cohen
2      Dan    Smith
3   George      NaN
4     Adam    Faber
```

#### Old Answer

Here's a solution for left-join behaviour, as in it doesn't keep `column_a` values that do not match any `column_b` values. This is slower than the above numpy/pandas solution because it uses two nested `iterrows` loops to build a python list.

```
tups = [(a1, a2) for i, (a1, b1) in df1.iterrows() 
                 for j, (a2, b2) in df2.iterrows()
        if b1 in b2]

(pd.DataFrame(tups, columns=['column_a', 'column_b'])
   .drop_duplicates('column_a')
   .reset_index(drop=True))

  column_a column_b
0     John    Moore
1  Michael    Cohen
2      Dan    Smith
3     Adam    Faber
```

Comment: Hm. But it's pure python solution. Could it be done with `pandas` or `numpy`? E.g. with combination of `apply`, `map`, `join`, `merge` etc

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler, well, that's one way to do it. I am however looking for something similat to what  Alex Yu is suggesting

Comment: This certainly could be improved! It's the first instinctive solution that came to mind. Does it run in an acceptable time on your amount of data? If so, why bother optimizing? ;)

Comment: @callmeGuy Maybe it would be better to clarify in question that "pandas/numpy solution" is requested. Otherwise - this solution is formally correct

Comment: Gotcha. My old answer performed quite poorly in my limited testing. I've edited in a newer, slightly faster solution - though it's less readable.

Comment: Ah-ha! That's exactly what I myself tried to find! Thank you!

Comment: The code would be more user-friendly (as well as faster) if you use `str.contains(x)` instead of `str.find(x).ge(0)`!   (I had to look up `pd.Series.ge()` -- FYI, it evaluates greater-than-or-equal-to, elementwise.)

Comment: I think this wont work if the join could create multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

My solution involves applying a function to the common column. I can't imagine it holds up well when df2 is large but perhaps someone more knowledgeable than I can suggest an improvement.

```
def strmerge(strcolumn):
    for i in df2['column_common']:
        if strcolumn in i:
            return df2[df2['column_common'] == i]['column_b'].values[0]

df1['column_b'] = df1['column_common'].apply(strmerge)

df1
    column_a    column_common   column_b
0   John        code            Moore
1   Michael     other           Cohen
2   Dan         ome             Smith
3   George      no match        None
4   Adam        word            Faber
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, readable and purely vectorized approach could be to have a `cross` join and then filter where columns `column_common` of one is substring of other:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
df.loc[df.column_common_x.eq('no match'),'column_b'] = pd.NA
df.loc[df.apply(lambda x:x.column_common_y.__contains__(x.column_common_x) or x.column_common_x == 'no match', axis=1), 
       ['column_a', 'column_b']].drop_duplicates(subset=['column_a'])
```

Output:

| column_a | column_b |
| --- | --- |
| John | Moore |
| Michael | Cohen |
| Dan | Smith |
| George |  |
| Adam | Faber |