# How to merge 2 dataframes based on two columns via string containment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is somewhat similar to this one: [How to merge pandas on string contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756025/how-to-merge-pandas-on-string-contains), but I need a different output and the problem itself is a bit more complex. So I have 2 dataframes similar to the ones below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ref_name':['city-louisville','city-louisville','city-louisville', 'town-lexington','town-lexington','town-lexington'], 'un_name1':['CPU1','CPU2','GPU1','CPU1','CPU2','GPU1'], 'value1':[10,15,28,12,14,14]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ref_name':['louisville','louisville','lexington','lexington'], 'un_name2':['CPU','GPU','CPU','GPU'], 'value2':[25,28,26,14]})
```

I need to join based on `ref_name` and `un_name` based on the substrings within them. They won't always be as clean as this, but I figured it made for a decent little example. So my desired output in this case would look something like this:

```
ref_name  |  un_name1  |  un_name2  | value1  |  value2
---------------------------------------------------------
louisville|  CPU1      |  CPU       |  10     |  25
louisville|  CPU2      |  CPU       |  15     |  25
louisville|  GPU1      |  GPU       |  28     |  28
lexington |  CPU1      |  CPU       |  12     |  26
lexington |  CPU2      |  CPU       |  14     |  26
lexington |  GPU1      |  GPU       |  14     |  14
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the most generic version that I can think of. Performance may be a problem if your dataframes are big.

```
mask1 = df2['ref_name'].apply(lambda value: df1['ref_name'].str.contains(value))
mask2 = df2['un_name2'].apply(lambda value: df1['un_name1'].str.contains(value))
mask = (mask1 & mask2).stack().rename_axis(['index2', 'index1'])
mask = mask[mask].index.to_frame(False)

result = mask.merge(df2, left_on='index2', right_index=True) \
             .merge(df1, left_on='index1', right_index=True)
```

Result:

```
 index2  index1  ref_name_x un_name2  value2       ref_name_y un_name1  value1
      0       0  louisville      CPU      25  city-louisville     CPU1      10
      0       1  louisville      CPU      25  city-louisville     CPU2      15
      1       2  louisville      GPU      28  city-louisville     GPU1      28
      2       3   lexington      CPU      26   town-lexington     CPU1      12
      2       4   lexington      CPU      26   town-lexington     CPU2      14
      3       5   lexington      GPU      14   town-lexington     GPU1      14
```

Trimming / renaming the columns is an excercise left for the OP.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!! Yes, trimming the excess columns is no problem at all, data lines up perfectly both in the above example and my messy dataset. Also feel like I should note that it didn't take too terribly long to run. For 1 dataframe with 1000 entries and the other with >6000 it took less than 10 seconds.