# How to join two pandas Dataframe by rule contains values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data source:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [
    'Some text 11.',
    'Good 2 number',
    'Other 33 not valid',
    '4 is good too even with 7'
]})
```

df1 look like

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

and the df2 looks like

```
                           b
0              Some text 11.
1              Good 2 number
2         Other 33 not valid
3  4 is good too even with 7
```

My goal is merge them if number from the column `df1.a` exists *in any position* in the column `df2.b`, but only exact number.
so the result should be:

```
a                         b
2              Good 2 number
4  4 is good too even with 7
```

I can modify the [solution on string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756025/how-to-merge-pandas-on-string-contains) but looks very complicated. In the real data the both source has more than 20k records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all numeric by [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to `DataFrame` with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), convert to integers and match by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with test if at least one True per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
mask = (df2['b'].str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
                .astype(int)
                .unstack()
                .reindex(df2.index)
                .isin(df1['a'])
                .any(axis=1))
df = df2[mask]
print (df)
                           b
1              Good 2 number
3  4 is good too even with 7
```

---

You can join all values of `df1['a']` by `|` for regex `or` with `\b\b` for words boundaries and pass to [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df1['a'])
df = df2[df2['b'].str.contains(pat)]
print (df)
                           b
1              Good 2 number
3  4 is good too even with 7
```

If need solution with `merge`:

```
s = df2['b'].str.extractall('(\d+)')[0].astype(int).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

df = df1.merge(df2.join(s.rename('a')),on='a')
print (df)
   a                          b
0  2              Good 2 number
1  4  4 is good too even with 7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I'm sorry to miss information that both source have more than 20k records on the test environment and possible more in the prod

Comment: @BrownBear - tehn second should be better, I guess

Comment: the second solution is that I was searching for, thank you once again. May be it can be put to the top of the answer )